# Why is variable NOT properly initialised in this BEGIN?

Tags: awk

In this gawk, it seems as if the ave=$4 is ignored in the BEGIN statement. It appears that ave has value 0 in the body of the first row:

```
cat trades.txt | gawk 'BEGIN{pos=0;ave=$4} {pos+=$3;ave=(0.1*$4)+(0.9*ave)} {print $2,pos,$4,ave}' > onPositions.txt
```

Comment: BEGIN no field; You ave=$4 == ave=""

Comment: Think - the BEGIN section is executed before the file is opened so what is the value of `$4` in the BEGIN section? Get rid of the UUOC in your code and get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `BEGIN` block is run before any data has been read. If you want to do something special one time after reading just the first record:

```
NR == 1 { ... init code here ... }
```

Comment: Can you give a full structure for this snippet please

Comment: The structure is the same as for any other block (like you already have for `BEGIN`) --- what the actual code should be, however, is another question. Do you intend for your print statement to run for all records including the first, or only starting with the second record (with `ave` set to `$4` from the first record)? If you want to print something for the first record, what should the value of `ave` be initialized to?